# How do i add an additional property to each element in array, how do i then use that property to affect the style of the output

Tags: php

How can i set a color to each object in array ?
For example i want to set  "Zen" (green) , "bless" (yellow).

```
$prices = array(
    " Zen " => $chk_prices['zen'],
    " Bless " => $chk_prices['bless'],
    " Credits " => $chk_prices['credit'], 
    " Chaos " => $chk_prices['chaos'], 
    " Creation " => $chk_prices['creation'],
    " Rena " => $chk_prices['rena'], 
    " Stone " => $chk_prices['stone'], 
    " Life " => $chk_prices['life'], 
    " Soul " => $chk_prices['soul']);
```

Can someone help me with this.
Thanks.

Comment: can you describe the expected output?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is unclear exactly what you are trying to do. Please take the time to review the [help on asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking), in particular [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  and update your question with details of what you have tried and your relevant code in a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so we have the information we need to be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like you need a multi dimensional array

$prices = array(
"Zen" => ["price" => $chk_prices['zen'], "color" => "green"],
and so on....
);

think of it like this

Zen is an array within an the $prices array (which now isn't the best name for it as it contains other properties not just prices)

```
$prices = array( 
   "zen" => array(
        "price" => $chk_prices['zen'],
        "color" => "#7396FF"
    ),
    "Bless " => array(
        "price" => $chk_prices['bless'],
        "color" => "#7396FF>"
    )
)
```

to access the price of zen you would use $prices['zen']['price']

a better way to do this would be to use objects, but that's a whole other conversion.

i edited it again, because now i see you want to add styling.

you cant add styling to the output in this way. you need to echo some code using the values from the array.

for instance

```
echo '<span style="color:'.$prices['zen']['color'].';">zen price is '.$prices['zen']['price'].'</span>';
```

[i haven't tested this code]

Comment: I get this error when i try this :  Warning: number_format() expects parameter 1 to be double, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\mod\market\market.php on line 152 also and this :Notice: Undefined variable: prices in C:\xampp\htdocs\mod\market\market.php on line 141

Comment: ok that because once you change your code like above, any processing that you do to the values afterwards needs to target the child array element such as $prices['zen']['price'] or $prices['zen']['color']

Comment: can u check the picture abovr , i want to real color this object in website.not color like object

Comment: i am trying like this but its not working  $prices = array(" Zen " => "<font color='#7396FF'>Zen</font>"  $chk_prices['zen']

Comment: i tryied with this and i get this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'color' (T_STRING), expecting ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mod\market\market.php on line 144

Comment: i amended my original answer. your question really i guess is how do add a property to an array and how do i use that property to affect the style output on the browser.

Comment: thats exactly i am close i get this errors now with your code https://ibb.co/g359vJ2